# OpAmp Inverter Circuit

Tags: voltage, adc, inverter, circuits

I have a single-ended input signal (0-10 kHz) and want to increase the input signal range for my ADC (AD4134) by inverting this signal and feeding original and inverted signal into the ADC. I use an AD8221 as an input OP-Amp. I came up by trial and error with the circuit on the RIGHT in the picture below. It works fine so far.

I later stumbled upon the proposed, generic circuit on the LEFT side (proposed in the ADC Datasheet, Figure 105). When I simulate it in LTSpice, they behave similar, even though the output signals of the LEFT circuit are a little bit lower with the same input signal compared to the RIGHT circuit. The common mode voltage is the same in both circuits. (differences in circuits are marked in blue)

[image]

Can anyone share an expert opinion on these circuits and their respective pros and cons? I am far from being an electronics expert and cannot make sense, if one of them would work better/has limits/... I would probably fall back to the LEFT circuit, as this is an "officially" recommended circuit (with which R and C values?) and not created by trail and error by my unexperienced self as the RIGHT one.